# error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')|

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function for matrix multiplication, it shows compilation error. But the multiplication part in the function gives the output in main function(exactly what i am expected).

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void matmul(int *x,int *y,int *z,int r1,int r2,int r3,int c1,int c2,int c3)
{
    int *a=x;
    int *b=y;
    int *c=z;
    int i,j,k,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
         for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
           {
           for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
               {
                    sum += *((*a+k)+(c1*j)) *  *(*b+(c2*k)+i);//compiler shows the error at this line
                                                              
               }
            *(*c+(j*c2)+i)=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
}


int main()
{
int a[3][3]={1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3},b[3][3]={1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3},c[3][3]={0};
int i,j,k,sum=0;
int r1,r2,c1,c2;
r1=3;r2=3;c1=3;c2=3;

matmul(a,b,c,3,3,3,3,3,3);
//multiplication part

for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
       {
           for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
               {
                    sum += *((*a+k)+(c1*j)) *  *(*b+(c2*k)+i);

               }
            *(*c+(j*c2)+i)=sum;
            sum=0;
       }


//displaying result (c[3][3])
for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
  {
       printf(" %d ",c[i][j]);
       if(j==c2-1)
         printf("\n");
  }
   return 0;
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
           {
               for(k=0;k<c1;k++)
                   {
                        sum += *((*a+k)+(c1*j)) *  *(*b+(c2*k)+i);

                   }
                *(*c+(j*c2)+i)=sum;
                sum=0;
           }.........................it gives the output in main function

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68607889/edit) the question to update it with the code rather than in comments where it is difficult to read and easily missed. Please ensure that it is a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code that anyone can use exactly as shown to reproduce the problem. For example, the code shown does not have the definition of `a`, `b` and `c` which is pretty important since the error is likely related to those variable types.

Comment: I tried to add the code but i can't....so i added screenshot of my code .Is that image is visible?

Comment: OT: if it's a compilation error, there's no program to execute... So something is wrong here. Post the code and the exact compiler message

Comment: I've added your code from the comments. But it is incomplete. Please edit it to add complete code.

Comment: "it shows compilation error" okay... post it!!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that code is pretty unreadable. Using multiple single letter variables and inconsistent formatting just makes the code very hard to understand. One obvious error is `*((*a+k)+(c1*j))`. Why are you trying to dereference that? The expression in brackets is an `int` and not a pointer. But because the code is so hard to understand can't suggest how to fix it.

Comment: now i added the full code

Comment: There are several problems here.  First, in `matmul`, what's the point of `a`, `b`, and `c`?  Just use `x`, `y`, and `z` directly.  Then, look at this expression:  `*((*a+k)+(c1*j))`.  It's immediately obvious that it's trying to dereference an integer, which is an error:  `*a` has type `int`, and `(*a+k)+(c1*j)` has type `int`.  The outer `*` attempts to dereference this, which makes no sense.  So, remove the outer `*`.  Then move on to the other bugs.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and the comment above gives you the exact reason for the first error.  Try to understand it.  Then you can try to fix it.  It would probably help a lot if you put this on hold, and instead tried a very basic array example, then a very basic pointer example.  Don't try to implement matrix multiply until you understand C arrays and pointers.

Comment: from my learning ..i thought *((*a+k)+(c1*j))  or  *(*a+k+c1*j) both are same and they will give the elements of a. it is wright or wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "the same"? That's pretty irrelevant for the error in question. They are both wrong. We have told you multiple times already - the expression inside the brackets `(*a+k)+(c1*j)` and even `*a+k+c1*j` is an `int` and not a pointer. And thus you cannot dereference it with `*`. If you cannot understand that basic fact then it really would benefit you to pause coding and review a good C book/tutorial first.

Comment: @SudhakaranN They *are* the same.  They're also both wrong.  Look at the inner expression:  `(*a+k)+(c1*j)`, which is equivalent to `*a+k+c1*j`.  That has an integer type, i.e. the type is `int`, right?  `a` is an `int *`, so `*a` is an `int`, and the other variables all have type `int`.  Now, look at what you're trying to do with it.  First, you put parentheses around it, which is fine.  So now you have `(value)` where `value` is an integer.  Then you try to apply the `*` operator to it, i.e. `*(value)`.  That's an error.  You cannot apply the unary `*` operator to an integer.

Comment: As has been said, you don't understand arrays and you don't understand pointers.  Work out some simpler examples until you do.  You're not ready for matrix multiply.

Comment: @SudhakaranN There's also a quick visual check you can make.  In `matmul`, the maximum pointer depth is one.  You have integer pointers, but no pointers-to-pointers, no arrays of pointers, no pointers to arrays, and no arrays of arrays.  That means that the maximum possible number of nested unary `*` operators in `matmul` is one.  If you have `*(...*(...))` anywhere in that function, then you have an error, since that has two nested unary `*` operators.  It's instantly clear that  it has a bug.  There are three instances of this in `matmul`.

Comment: Also, `main` declares 2d arrays (arrays of arrays), and tries to pass them to `matmul`.  In `main`, `a` is declared as `int a[3][3]`.  When passed to `matmul`, it is passed as an `int (*)[3]`, which is a pointer to an array of three integers.  The declarations in `matmul` are incompatible with those pointer types.  Multi-dimensional pointers are a little tricky in C, and you need to have a solid understanding of the simpler cases before you attempt to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are trying to pass the 2D matrix as a flat 1D array using a `int` pointer.

But in this line:

```
*((*a+k)+(c1*j))
```

you have two pointer dereferences, i.e.

```
*((*a+k)+(c1*j))
^  ^
|  |
|  Dereference
|
Dereference
```

Dereferencing twice on a pointer to `int` is wrong. The first time you'll get an `int` and the second time you try to dereferece the `int` which is obviously wrong.

I'll suggest that you use syntax `Pointer[index]` instead.

So if you want to access an element in a 2D matrix M like

```
M[some_row][some_col]  // M as 2D
```

using a 1D representation `m`, you should do like

```
m[some_row * NUMBER_OF_COLS + some_col]  // m as 1D representation of M
```

That's much easier to read and understand.

So probably you want

```
*((*a+k)+(c1*j)) --> a[j * c1 + k]
```

That said... you should consider using real 2D arrays (aka array of array) instead of a flat 1D array.

**Other notes**

When you do matrix multiplication like

```
A[arows][acols] * B[brows][bcols]
```

it's a **requirement** that `acols` **is equal to** `brows`. Further the result is

```
A[arows][acols] * B[brows][bcols] --> C[arows][bcols]
```

or in shorter form

```
A[x][y] * B[y][z] --> C[x][z]
```

So you don't need to pass 6 integers to the function. There are only 3 unique values.

Comment: I agree your point (Dereferencing twice on a pointer to int is wrong).  Eg: int a=2;int *x=&a; printf("%d",**x); I know this is wrong.

Comment: From my learning , in a 2D array (a[2][2])  a---->address of  whole 1st row   ,a+1--->address of whole  2nd row , *a---->address of first element in 1st row , **a--->value in the address(*a) which means the first element of the first array .   Is this wright or wrong

Comment: I thought ....for example at i=0,j=0,k=0 the expression *((*a+k)+(c1*j))--->*( *a +0 +c1*0)--->*(*a+0)--->**a . **a--->first element of first row in a[x][x]